# Expiration date issue for Amazon RDS SSL certificate

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl-certificate, amazon-rds

Today i get an email from AWS that says "**Update Your Amazon RDS and Amazon Aurora SSL/TLS Certificates by August 22, 2024**". So after that i changed the certificate from rds-ca-2019 to rds-ca-rsa4096-g1 via CLI. But DB instance certificate expiration date doesn't change.

Command : `aws rds modify-db-instance --db-instance-identifier <db_instance_identifier> --ca-certificate-identifier rds-ca-rsa4096-g1 --apply-immediately`

Am i missing something ? Thanks in advance

Comment: Got the same and clueless on how it should be done, I can setup a new CA certificate under RDS and Aurora but within my client applications, Im not specifying the certificate name. Its just ssl parameter set to True when using db driver (node js application)

Answer (score 6):

Couldn't comment as I don't have enough reputation.

According to the docs
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.SSL.html

"When you use the rds-ca-rsa2048-g1, rds-ca-rsa4096-g1, or rds-ca-ecc384-g1 CA with a database, RDS manages the DB server certificate on the database. RDS rotates the DB server certificate automatically before it expires."

I interpret that as the DB instance certificate expiration date will be rotated automatically before it expires on August 22, 2024, as long as we update to the new certificates.

Under the old certificate (rds-ca-2019) "This CA expires in 2024 and doesn't support automatic server certificate rotation."
Hence updating to the new CA, which the original poster did, is sufficient, as it supports automatic server certificate rotation.

Answer (score 3):

Sign in to the **AWS Management Console**: https://console.aws.amazon.com/rds/.

Choose **Databases**, and then choose the DB instance that you want to modify.

Choose **Modify**. The Modify DB instance page appears.

In **Connectivity** section -> **Certificate authority**: I changed to **rds-ca-ecc384-g1** and expiration date will be increase.

Comment: Is there a way to specify this using the CDK for example?  Or is it necessary to do it manually?

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you updated to **rds-ca-rsa4096-g1**. It has validity upto **May 21, 2121** with automatic cert rotation.
This cert support rotation, so certificate expire yearly and rotated automatically

> The validity of DB server certificate depends on the DB engine and DB
> engine version. If the DB engine version supports rotating the
> certificate without restart, the validity of the DB server certificate
> is 1 year. Otherwise the validity is 3 years.